# how do i change the post body before it reaches the server?

Tags: fiddler

Trying to code my first fiddler script.

How do i change the post body before it reaches the server?

I mean, i fill the form, click submit, then pause to change what i want, and, finally, send to server.

I found this script to change the response, but i want to change the request.

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.bayden.com") && oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type","text/html")){
  oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
  oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('<b>','<u>');
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863044/how-to-send-two-to-modify-the-body-request has a clear answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
if (oSession.uriContains("/myposturl")) {
   if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("POST")){
      oSession["x-breakrequest"]="pause";
   }
}
```

OnBeforeRequest

Comment: is there any parameter that can let me change the value from script.for example there is parameter guid that contains a id i want to change the value of that post parameter with fiddler script.