# How to send two to modify the Body Request

Tags: fiddler

I'm running into a small roadblock. English is poor, difficulty in expressing

I want to modify the Request in the body and sent two consecutive Request

Original content:

```
POST http://www.text.com/next?cyt=1 is
HTTP/1.1
Host: www.text.com
User-Agent: Million/1.0.0
Content-Length: 58
Accept: * / *
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language:
Content-Type: application / x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: S = hveisf76n2lrnpvbeng8ivrat6
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

S = hveisf76n2lrnpvbeng8ivrat6 & step = ashf87afs0a2e4
```

An attempt was made ​​to modify the Body and send to:

```
S = hveisf76n2lrnpvbeng8ivrat6 & step = qarker11s77ar
```

Another attempt to modify the Body and send to:

```
S = hveisf76n2lrnpvbeng8ivrat6 & step = qarker22s88ar
```

Request sent twice modified body

I try to do the code:

---

```
 static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) 
{ 
   if(oSession.uriContains("http://www.text.com/next?cyt=1"))
   {
      var strBody=oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();                                                    
      strBody=strBody.replace("step=ashf87afs0a2e4","step=qarker11s77ar");
      oSession.utilSetRequestBody(strBody);

         var strBody1=oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();
         strBody1=strBody.replace("step=qarker11s77ar","step=qarker22s88ar");
         oSession.utilSetRequestBody(strBody1);
   }
}
```

---

The question that arises is:

> S = hveisf76n2lrnpvbeng8ivrat6 & step = qarker11s77ar

Successful transmission, but

> S = hveisf76n2lrnpvbeng8ivrat6 & step = qarker22s88ar

And can not be sent, how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: You indicate that you get a successful transmission with the first set of values, and you say that the second set of values 'can not be sent'.  Is it correct that you are not seeing any errors but the problem us that you would like a second request to be issued and it is not being issued?

Answer (score 1):

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) 
{ 
if(oSession.uriContains("http://www.text.com/next?cyt=1"))
{
var strBody=oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();                                                    
  strBody=strBody.replace("step=ashf87afs0a2e4","step=qarker11s77ar");
  strBody=strBody.replace("step=qarker11s77ar","step=qarker22s88ar");
     oSession.utilSetRequestBody(strBody);
}
}
```