# Testing multiple parameters web api c# - fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I need help.

I have a method: `PostCustomer`

> HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer([FromBody] CustomerRec Logs, [FromBody] Customer customer)

Now my problem is how will I able to test this through fiddler

I know I need to call for example:

```
"//api/customer/PostCustomer"
```

- But how will I pass parameters on this?
- I'm testing this using fiddler.

Comment: Might I suggest the chrome plugin postman - fantastic tool for API testing. Also have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215170/how-do-i-change-the-post-body-before-it-reaches-the-server

Comment: I also use that for testing. But what I want to see is on how to test this on fiddler particularly.

Comment: do you mean telerik Fiddler Web Debugger??

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to build the url request (passing the parameters for your method through url)

If that's it, it should be like this

api/customer/PostCustomer/?FirstParameter=Example&SecondParemeter=Example2

If you mean the request itself

```
string postData = string.Format("?FirstParameter=" + txt_First.Text + "&SecondParemeter=" + txt_Last.Text);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("..../api/customer/PostCustomer"/" + postData);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        }

        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                var responseValue = string.Empty;


                // grab the response  
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd(); // read the full response

                    }
                }
                if (responseValue != "")
                {
                    //Do something here if response is not empty

                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // Handle error
        }
```

PS: Can't comment on post because it asks for 50+ reputation...

Comment: I'm actually passing two objects as parameters

Comment: Ah Sorry I didn't understood that.
Have you tried serializing the object and send the variable with the serialized object inside?